# Getting stylesheet object from ownerNode(style tag)

Tags: javascript, cssom

I have a multiple `style` tags in my webpage, and i want to manipulate the `cssRules` in them. How can I get the `styleSheet` as in `document.styleSheets` object from a style element. A way could be scanning all the `styleSheets` in `document.styleSheets` and match its `ownerNode` with my `style` element object. Is there any better way that this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/semantics.html#the-style-element , the style element implements the `LinkStyle` interface which by following the references can lead one to http://dev.w3.org/csswg/cssom/#the-linkstyle-interface which indicates that there is a `sheet` property you can access for each style element (as with `<link rel="stylesheet">`)--as long as they are `text/css`, the default. From there you can get the more specialized CSSStyleSheet interface you are looking for (i.e., the one with `cssRules`).

```
<style>
  p {color:blue;}
</style>
<script>

  var h = document.getElementsByTagName('style')[0];
  alert(h.sheet.cssRules[0].cssText); // "p { color: blue; }"

</script>
```